# ValueError: bad input shape ()-Scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I want to plot the best fitting line for a scatter plot,regarding which i have posted a question earlier,with some people's help I was able to tackle it to some extent,but again I'm facing problem...
This is the Code I used to plot my data using Scikit, I got code from this (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html)

```
 for j in lat :
            l=94*j
            i=l-92
            for lines in itertools.islice(input_file, i, l):
                    lines=lines.split()
                    p.append(float(Decimal(lines[0])))
                    vmr.append(float(Decimal(lines[3])))
X =np.matrix(vmr)
y =np.matrix(p)
##########################################################################
Fit regression model
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X[0,0], y[0,0]).predict(X)
y_lin = svr_lin.fit(X[920], y[920]).predict(X)
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(X[920], y[920]).predict(X)
###########################################################################
look at the results
lw = 2
plt.scatter(X, y, color='darkorange', label='data')
plt.hold('on')
plt.plot(X, y_rbf, color='navy', lw=lw, label='RBF model')
plt.plot(X, y_lin, color='c', lw=lw, label='Linear model')
plt.plot(X, y_poly, color='cornflowerblue', lw=lw, label='Polynomial model')
plt.xlabel('H2O VMR')
plt.ylabel('Pressure(Pa)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I'm getting an error like this.

```
 ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

for line

```
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X[0,0], y[0,0]).predict(X)
```

I guess it is the shape that I have given is causing the  problem,I don't know what to give in those brackets so i was just trying with different numbers,there are 920 rows in my data so i tried giving 920,then the error was :

```
IndexError: index 920 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I'm really new to this,any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Why do people always throw away the good stuff of error-messages/traces. It probably exactly tells you which line throws this error. Well... Obviously some arrays have bad dimensions. Check your shapes of X, y, and co. **Well, you edited it**: now check the shape of X after y_rbf = ... as it's an array with only one element (or at least a first-dimension of 1). Of course you can't index 920. The problems are probably in the code which generates vmr, which is converted to some np-array which does not look like what you want.

Comment: So. If you got 5 mins experience with numpy, you should see, that this a problem, right? I'm off for now. Check sklearn's docs to understand what shapes are needed. Check numpy for how to work with arrays and check your shapes within your code after all your steps. This will lead you to a solution (at least something will run at the end).

Comment: Show the shape of X and y. Also why are you sending only single elements in fit()? Put all X and y in it

Comment: This is the output I got when i tried to print the shape of X and y           ((1L, 920L), (1L, 920L))

Comment: There is something wrong in `vmr` and `p`. Can you show some samples of your data?

Comment: vmr:-[0.0236, 0.0234, 0.0232, 0.023, 0.0229, 0.0228, 0.0227, 0.0223, 0.0222, 0.022, 0.0212, 0.0208, 0.0204, 0.02, 0.0196, 0.0192, ..................0.0184, 0.0174,   4.03e-06, 2.75e-06]       p:[101440.0, 101320.0, 101030.0, 100630.0, 100100.0, 99444.0, 98676.0, 97779.0, 96727.0, 95517.0, 94150.0, .....................92626.0, 90945.0, 89111.0, 87133.0, 85016.0]

Comment: I solved my problem using seaborn.regplot()                                                    ThankYou so much